# Do I have to publish own QGIS plugins?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, license, pyqt, qt-designer

If I develop QGIS plugins for my company do I have to make them available to others? I use QT-Designer and think that it also depends on the question how you develop your plugins, right?

For example:
If I'd work for public authorities they could be totally fine with publishing my plugins as there is no competition between them and because you don't have to gain a high ROI.

But: If I work for a private business that has a lot of competitors than my CEO could have a problem if I'd tell him that I develop a plugin for QGIS that every rival firm could use without contributing to the expenses we had for developing the plugin.
I indeed think that it is the duty of companies who use QGIS to contribute time or money to the QGIS project itself in order to keep the project "healthy" but this must be made apart from sharing plugin sourcecode in many cases.

Comment: Do you mean, if you make a QGIS plugin, do you have to make it available for public download from the Internet in order for others to use it? The answer is no, regardless of how you develop your plugin.

Comment: If you develop QGIS plugins for your company, whether you have to make them available to others will depend on your company's policies.

Comment: Just want to mention that QGIS and all related plugins are **open-source**. You should make sure that your company understands that making a plugin available would allow anyone to see the source code.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Do you have to publish it?**

Legally, The GPL License of PyQGIS forces you to share the code only with your "client", therefore your company.

So No, you don't have to publish it. You can keep them internally, create your own repository, and share with who you want.

But note that whoever receives the code is allowed to pass it on by the terms of the GPL.

**Should you publish it?**

YOU PROBABLY SHOULD!

If you think that your plugin can be useful to others, or even serve as a base for creating a more generic plugin, them you should publish it or, at least, share the code in github or something similar.

You are probably using other's plugins and code as well. Nice, right?

Comment: "The Open Source police won't go after you" sounds like it's being tolerated despite not being legal. Even if you tell somebody about it, it's perfectly legal to keep it internal.

Comment: I will edit it then.